# SQL Union with CTE and Sum

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, union, common-table-expression

I'm a complete novice with SQL and have two queries down to the results I want, but I think I'm not using `UNION` correctly to combine them.  I had some help on this site earlier with a portion of the query.
Below is a shortened version of what I have.

```
WITH RemoveData
     AS (SELECT a.PLANT_NO,
                a.ALLOC_WHDV_VOL,
                a.KW_CTR_REDELIVERED_HV,
                a.MTR_NO,
                a.MTR_SFX,
                a.TRNX_ID,
                a.REC_STATUS_CD,
                MAX(a.ACCT_DT) ACCT_DT
         FROM   GasStmt a
                INNER JOIN SettleSum c
                  ON a .= c.TRNX_ID
                     AND a.MTR_NO
                         ||a.MTR_SFX = c.MTR_NO
                                       ||c.MTR_SFX
                LEFT OUTER JOIN FuelsCat d
                  ON a.TRNX_ID = d.TRNX_ID
                     AND a.MTR_NO
                         ||a.MTR_SFX = d.MTR_NO
                                       ||d.MTR_SFX
         WHERE  a.REC_STATUS_CD = 'RR'
         GROUP  BY a.PLANT_NO,
                   a.ALLOC_WHDV_VOL,
                   a.KW_CTR_REDELIVERED_HV,
                   a.MTR_NO,
                   a.MTR_SFX,
                   a.TRNX_ID,
                   a.REC_STATUS_CD
         HAVING COUNT(a.REC_STATUS_CD) > 2) 
SELECT plant_no                   "PlantNumber",
       SUM(-a.ALLOC_WHDV_VOL)     "PlantStandardGrossWellheadMcf",
       SUM(KW_CTR_REDELIVERED_HV) "KeepWholeResidueMMBtu"
FROM   RemoveData a
GROUP  BY plant_no
UNION
SELECT a.PLANT_NO            "PlantNumber",
       SUM(a.ALLOC_WHDV_VOL) "PlantStandardGrossWellheadMcf",
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN a.REC_STATUS_CD = 'RR' THEN -a.KW_CTR_REDELIVERED_HV
             ELSE a.KW_CTR_REDELIVERED_HV
           END)              "KeepWholeResidueMMBtu"
FROM   GasStmt a
       INNER JOIN SettleSum c
         ON a.TRNX_ID = c.TRNX_ID
            AND a.MTR_NO
                ||a.MTR_SFX = c.MTR_NO
                              ||c.MTR_SFX
       LEFT OUTER JOIN FuelsCat d
         ON a.TRNX_ID = d.TRNX_ID
            AND a.MTR_NO
                ||a.MTR_SFX = d.MTR_NO
                              ||d.MTR_SFX
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT MTR_NO,
                               MTR_SFX,
                               TRNX_ID,
                               REC_STATUS_CD,
                               MAX(ACCT_DT) ACCT_DT
                        FROM   GasStmt
                        WHERE  REC_STATUS_CD = 'RR'
                        GROUP  BY MTR_NO,
                                  MTR_SFX,
                                  TRNX_ID,
                                  REC_STATUS_CD
                        HAVING COUNT(TRNX_ID) > 1) b
         ON a.MTR_NO = b.MTR_NO
            AND a.TRNX_ID = b.TRNX_ID
            AND a.Rec_Status_Cd = b.REC_STATUS_CD
            AND a.Acct_Dt = b.ACCT_DT
WHERE  TO_CHAR(a.PROD_DT, 'YYYY') >= TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -36), 'YYYY')
       AND a.STATUS_UNIT_TM_CD = 'M'
       AND b.MTR_NO IS NULL
GROUP  BY a.PLANT_NO
```

The above query returns:

```
PlantNumber | PlantStandardGrossWellheadMcf    |KeepWholeResidueMMBtu
2           | 0                                | -3.96
2           | 80                               |  100
43          | 150                              |  0
133         | 75                               |  0
```

If I run the first query with the CTE by itself, here's what I get:

```
PlantNumber | PlantStandardGrossWellheadMcf  |KeepWholeResidueMMBtu
2           | 0                              |-3.96
```

Running the second query by itself, here's an example of sample data I get:

```
PlantNumber | PlantStandardGrossWellheadMcf    |KeepWholeResidueMMBtu
2           | 80                               |  100
43          | 150                              |  0
133         | 75                               |  0
```

My intended result is to combine the data based on plant number.  Can that be done with UNION or am I doing something wrong?  This is what I'm hoping to achieve:

```
PlantNumber | PlantStandardGrossWellheadMcf    |KeepWholeResidueMMBtu
2           | 80                               |  96.04
43          | 150                              |  0
133         | 75                               |  0
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried to make some of it shorter and crunched some things up.  I changed it a little, hopefully it's more read-able.

Comment: You're much better off cutting your problem down to the shortest possible example. No one wants to have to read all that.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform aggregate functions on the results of a UNION statement as a sub-query. There may be some variations depending on your specific DBMS, but This sample meta-code should explain the concept:

```
SELECT "Results".ColA, "Results".SUM(ColB), "Results".SUM(ColC)
FROM (
      SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC
      FROM SomeTable1
      INNER JOIN SomeOtherTable1
      WHERE Criteria

      UNION

      SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC
      FROM SomeTable2
      INNER JOIN SomeOtherTable2
      WHERE Criteria
     ) "Results"

GROUP BY "Results".ColA
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I tried that earlier after looking at a previous user's post.  When I try: `SELECT PLANT_NO, SUM(a.ALLOC_WHDV_VOL), SUM(KW_CTR_REDELIVERED_HV) FROM ( ...my above query... )GROUP BY PLANT_NO` It says PLANT_NO is an invalid identifier.  If I remove the group by it says that KW_CTR_REDELIVERED_HV is an invalid identifier.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You might need to specify aliases, then. I've edited my response to show that the entire UNION statement is aliased with the name "Results" and each SELECT and GROUP BY then also specifying the "Results" item.

You could also try defining the UNION in a _with_ statement and then selecting/grouping from it: `WITH (SELECT... UNION SELECT...) AS "Results"
SELECT "Results".ColA, "Results".SUM(ColB), "Results".SUM(ColC)
GROUP BY "Results".ColA`

Comment: Thanks again for the quick response.  It seems like it has to be an alias issue, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.  It either says invalid identifier or query not ended correctly.  I've tried `GROUP BY Results.PLANT_NO`, `"Results".PLANT_NO`, `PlantNumber', and just about everything other combination I can think of.  I can't figure out how to reference the columns from the subquery.

Comment: In your code above you have PLANT_NO aliased as "PlantNumber" in the Union statement. If that's how your full code is, you need to `GROUP BY Results.PlantNumber` since that's the column name as returned by said subquery.

Comment: It is an extremely complex statement, there are probably simpler ways of achieving the results you need, possibly without needing to use UNION or subqueries, even. Without insight to your data structure or business needs, I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. Personally, whenever I end up backing myself into a corner, I like to start over from scratch. Sometimes starting from the beginning after working on something for so long you can see new, less-complex methods that you hadn't thought about before.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, Joshua.  I think that's the best advice.  I'm sure there is a more simple way to do it, I need to start from scratch again.  Sorry about the formatting issues originally!